# python ignore blank values csv loop

Tags: python, csv

I am looping through an excel file and I am making two columns a dictionary then into a list. I when looping though the list if the 2nd column has a blank it errors out. How can i get the 2nd column to ignore blanks and keep the loop going.

```
mydict = df1.groupby(['first'])['second'].apply(list).to_dict()
qry =list(' '.join(value) for key, value in mydict.items() if 'exampleword' in key)
qryCounted =Counter(" ".join(qry).split(" ")).items()
print(sorted(qryCounted,key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0])))
```

The error i get is

```
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected string or Unicode, float found
```

Comment: what error you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to convert the element to string first.

```
 qry =list(' '.join(str(value)) for key, value in mydict.items() if 'exampleword' in key)
```

--- update ---

it the value is list

```
 qry =list(' '.join(map(str,value))) for key, value in mydict.items() if 'exampleword' in key)
```

Comment: That breaks everything down to a letter count.

Comment: @jumpman8947 try the update. I write the idea, you need convert the float to string